# Exterior Retaining Wall Leaning Options

Tags: foundation, exterior, retaining-wall

MY house was built in the mid 70's and has foundation issues everywhere. I recently spotted one of my retaining walls leaning. I have explored the cost to have my foundation company place more deadman anchors to hold my property up. Before I confirmed that action plan, I wanted to double check for other more-permanent and cost-effective options.

https://imgur.com/a/Y6rEQE4

Comment: If the house has foundation issues the best advice would be to address those before worrying about a retaining wall.  The wall does not look to be a big issue. I see no cracks or crumbling. that would be evident if the wall had substantial movement.

Comment: OP, is the wall "leaning" where it meets the house too?

Comment: The foundation issues in the house have been handled with 7 deadman anchors with epoxy work to prevent leaking.

Comment: The wall does seem to be leaning where it meets the house, but at a smaller amount. It looks like the top part of the walls has previous had issues and had been fixed with some manual movement and some cement patching. Some of the cracks have become more evident, but in a small amount like a hairline crack.